# Override a function inside a class assigned to a variable

Tags: php, class

It seems quite simple.  I do a :

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

For ONLY the variable `$result` that is a mysqli_result class I want to change the `$result->fetch_assoc()` function to still call the inherited function, but to then adjust one field, sort of:

```
public function fetch_assoc()
{
    $row = parent::fetch_assoc();
    // Do complex stuff to a row
    $row['SUM'] = $row['SUM'] + $GLOBALS['some_number'];
    // Return the row
    return $row;
}
```

Then do a sort of override of:

```
$result->fetch_assoc = above_function;
```

I only want the single `$result` mysqli_result class overridden and not other mysqli_result classes used afterwards.  There must be a quick and simple way to do this.

**NOTE:** What I am trying to do to the field is far more complex than shown, I just did this simple addition for simplicity.

Comment: Can't you just modify the single instance of `$result` *after* calling `fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: Obsidian Age - No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the method by assigning another function to it in the way that you suggested in the example in your question. It is possible to assign a closure to a property with the same name of an existing method, but that does not override the method. It's still just a property that has a function as a value.

You could theoretically extend the `mysqli_result` class, but I don't know how you'd get `mysqli::query()` to return it.

The only way I can think of to override it is by wrapping the result object in a class that provides the additional functionality.

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$result = new class($result) {
    private $result;

    public function __construct($result) {
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    public function fetch_assoc() {
        $row = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
        // Do extra stuff to $row
        return $row;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return $this->result->$name(...$arguments);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought so, however I need to do loads more, like get the field types, etc.  Ended up resorting to plan B